# Are there general conditions for limit at infinity to be non-finite for $f(x)-g(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

If $\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty} f(x)= \infty$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow\infty} g(x)= \infty$. Are there any general conditions that could be placed on the two functions such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)-g(x)$ is non-finite i.e. equal to $\infty$ or $-\infty$?

Comment: Well, when $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\ne 1$ that happens. In other cases as well, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, something like $f(x) \ge 2 g(x)$, or more generally $\liminf_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} > 1$.

Probably one could start from there and invent lots of different conditions.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x)-g(x)=f(x)(1-\frac{g(x)}{f(x)})$$

thus if $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}= 1$$
then we can say nothing.

as an example,
take $f(x)=x^2+\frac 1x, g(x)=x^2$

and
$f(x)=x^2+x, g(x)=x^2$.